# How to highlight code when posting on a website dynamically?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm having a website made with django it is basically a tutorial website and i want to highlight code dynamically into my tutorials what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using some JavaScript framework for it. For example, [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) or [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/). Pass the code you want to highlight through your `view`-function to a django template and use JS to color it.